# When i am trying to subtract a smaller negative value from a bigger negative value ,int type is returining a positive value

Tags: java, int, type-conversion

When i am trying to **subtract** a **smaller negative value** from a **bigger negative value** ,int type is returining a **positive value**.

can anyone explain why?

Here is the code:

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=-2147483648;
    int b =a-18;
    System.out.println(b);


}
```

}
output:
2147483630

Comment: What you're observing is called "overflow".  The `int` data type has a finite range.  When it exceeds that range, it starts back at the other end of that range.

Comment: No.it isn't
In that question.if limit exceeds .then count goes in reverse oreder.Here value is right.but sign is wrong,,,

Comment: And in what way is your observation different?

Comment: ok.got it.......
if u surstract 1 from  -2147483648  ,it prints 214783648 which is maximum range on positive side/.Thanks